# Responsive DataTable not updating

Tags: datatables, responsive

I have an issue with DataTables and the responsive function while using button column visibility.

If I pick all the columns to be visible as demonstrated in the screenshot below it works fine, the responsiveness works great. 
[All columns chosen, which triggers the responsiveness](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cnz3P.png).

But once I try to hide columns for example the ones [in this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dTQVr.png) the values in the responsive field does not update until I click on the + and - sign again so that it updates.

Is there anyone who knows if this can be solved?

```
My fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zchthgzv/65/
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid that's just how it works with DataTables 1.10.16 and Responsive 2.2.1. As you say, it doesn't dynamically update those currently open groups - they need to be closed and reopened. This may change in a future release but it's not currently scheduled.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Colin, hopefully this will get fixed later on. Thanks anyway.